# IOS: map with route

Tags: ios, mapkit, routes

In my app I should create a viewcontroller where inside should be a map;
In this map I should see a route that connects two pins. (because I have two pins)
So I want to know what's the best solution to have this result; again I should see two type of route: a route with car and a walking route...
is there a framework that can help me? (because mapkit don't solve my problem)
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a UIWebView, you can use javascript and get the functionality basically for free, because as you said, MapKit does not provide that functionality. It's pretty simple, check [this google maps tutorial for the basics](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/tutorial-iphone). Of course this way, you get all the pros and cons of html and javascript.

You simply write your javascript code into a html (here is `map.html`) which you put in your project folder and initiate that html file like this.

```
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"map" ofType:@"html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
  [self.mapView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

You call a javascript function from objective-c like this. here, in the map.html there is a javascript function called `setMarkerAtPosition(latitude, longitude)`. pretty straight forward.

```
[self.mapView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"setMarkerAtPosition(%f,%f)",latlong.latitude, latlong.longitude]];
```

**Edit upon request:**

You add a UIWebView and hook it up to the controller (if you don't know how to do this, you should definitely step back from this and do some basic tutorials)  (don't forget to synthesize the mapView. again, if you don't know what that is do basic reading)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *mapView;
@end
```

Then put the following code in your viewDidLoad method.It creates a NSString and initializes it with the contents of your local html file (just like already posted). Then, you call loadHTMLString method of your UIWebView. the html string is based on your local html file `map.html` (just name it that and just drag and drop into your project if you have not added it yet).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
    NSError *error = nil;
  // create NSString from local HTML file and add it to the webView
  NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"map" ofType:@"html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
  [self.mapView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];  
  [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.mapView];
}
```

Next add a button to your view (interface builder, you should know how) and connect it to a method. Inside this method, put this code (this will give you a route in germany by the way)

```
[self.mapView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"calculateRoute(50.777682, 6.077163, 50.779347, 6.059429)"];
```

Last, use this as the content of your `map.html` file (note; there is also some useless stuff inside, but you can figure that out later. I deleted all the code you don't need to display a route, but there is much in the header that useless):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.de/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=DE"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="json.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1");</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> google.load("maps", "3", {other_params:"sensor=false"}); </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

  // global variables
  var currentPosition;
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  // calculates the current userlocation
  function getCurrentLocation(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    } else {
      alert('geolocation not supported');
    }
  }

  // called when the userLocation has been located
  function success(position) {
    currentPosition = position;
    drawMap(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  }

  // called when the userLocation could not be located
  function error(msg) {
    alert('error: ' + msg);
  }

  // calculate and route from-to and show on map
  function calculateRoute(fromLat, fromLong, toLat, toLong){
      var start =  new google.maps.LatLng(fromLat, fromLong);
      var end = new google.maps.LatLng(toLat, toLong);
      var request = {
          origin:start, 
          destination:end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
             directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          }
      });
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }


  // draws the inital map and shows userlocation
  function drawMap(latitude, longitude) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
      var myOptions = {
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoom: 15,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {if(infowindow){infowindow.close();}});
      setMarkerAtPosition(latitude, longitude);
  }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="getCurrentLocation()">
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can just go to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/and look at the code and paste it. It doesn't take much knowledge. And it would take not more than one hour to get the necessary knowledge. I build an app that displays a route without any javascript knowledge in under two hours.. other people can propably do it in 15 mins. I'd say give it a try, it really is simple

Comment: if you have safari go to developer in the top bar show "show web information". or just right click "show sourecode"

Comment: Hi I saw something about javascript for map using a webview, but I don't understand what's the way to set my file map.html... if I go in this page "https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple" I have html code and js but I don't understand how to use them...have you some tutorials?

Comment: as shown above, you just add your html file to your project and load it up as shown above, all the code you need to load a html file is above, and I posted a tutorial too. By the way, I get page not found on your link.

Comment: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript    /examples/directions-simple   ... I put a space...so I take its html code and after? If I do in this way I don't see a map in my webview

Comment: no why would you use this code? the page does not show a map. have you actually looked at the tutorial link I posted?

Comment: ok, first thing: Do I should use a file html inside my app or call an URL for uiwebview? - second thing: can you show me how to load in a webview a map that show me direction (street or walk) from a marker point to another?

Comment: wow...it work fine...now can you tell me where do you take code for map.htlm? after I have some question: 1) can I write in the marker popup? 2)if I want a walking route?

Comment: do you can't expalin me these things? with these information I finished my doubts...after I accept your answer...please..

Comment: look your question was how to display a route. I answered that. this is how this site works. If you have a question on how to use javascript, open a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Please See this tutorial to draw polyline or route in mkmapview

1>[Draw route using mapkit](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65)

2>From versions above ios4.0 You can use [MKOverlayPathView See Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayPathView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can ask Google Maps for that route, parse the json answer and display a line as PolyLineView on your map. That's the way it works on the iOS Maps app.
Check the Google Maps Route API at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: can I use Google Directions API in my app?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to figure out all the code yourself, because no Framework exists on iOS to use it out of the box. You can also look at the project https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions

Comment: but I understand, I have to parsing xml of google direction api, and after I can use a simple project that show me how to make lines in my mapview...it's ok

Answer (score 1):

You can use a web view and open the url

https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=START_LOCATION&daddr=DESTINATION_LOCATION

this will open a web page as you want.

You can enter either pair of(lat, long) or direct city name.

Hope this will help you